# Java byte for loop won't stop running when index < 128

Tags: java, byte

I have this code that runs but never stops.

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (byte index = 0; index < 128; index++)
      {
          System.out.println(index);
      }
   }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why it keeps looping.

Comment: Because `byte` is signed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java, `byte` can only represent values between -128 and 127. This means that *every possible value of `index`* is less than 128, and the loop cannot terminate with the current condition. When `index` reaches 127, it simply overflows to -128 and the loop carries on.

For more details on Java's integral types, see the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).

Comment: Thanks very much. I will mark as correct. One thing that confused me is in my Java reference it says "When byte and short values are used in an expression they are promoted to int when the expression is evaluated".

Answer (score 3):

byte is a 1-byte type, so condition i < 128 is always true. **When you add 1 to 127 it overflows and becomes -128 and again starts from there**.Thats why you are getting infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, why? It could not overflow and stop, right? Why does it loop that way? Thanks Vipul